# Is it possible to programmatically scroll to a specific element in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, scroll, android-linearlayout

My LinearLayout has a few TableRow elements, each of which contain a TextView and an EditText. Basically, the LinearLayout acts as a form. For various reasons, I'm not using a TableLayout, as it has been too problematic to configure to my needs.

I need to make sure each EditText field has been filled. Currently, if the user leaves out a field, my app will simply generate an error message telling the user which field had been left blank. To improve user experience, I want to allow the LinearLayout to scroll automatically to the TableRow so the user could easily find the blank field.

Is this possible with a LinearLayout?

Comment: Have you tried to setFocus to that EditText? EditText ET=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETID);
ET.requestFocus();

Comment: Just tried it. It's pretty much exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: at least a comment upvote whould be nice for the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the desired layout view's focus? [Android View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29)